# Accessing Instance Variables from Another Class

Tags: java, permissions, instance

If you want to get straight to the problem, skip this paragraph. As practice, I am trying to write a Java program that simulates an economy, and to that end wrote a company class. The idea was to have, say, a dozen of them, wrap their earnings into a normalvariate function, and that would be the economy.

I wrote a separate class to graph the companies' outputs using JFreeChart. However, I can't access the ArrayList that I write the amount of money for each year to from the graphing class. I understand the best way to do this is probably with getters, but it didn't seem to work, so if that is your advice, could you please provide an example? Thanks!

The company:

```
public class ServiceProvider implements Company {
    //Variables


    public ArrayList getRecords(){
        return records;
    }

    public ServiceProvider(){
        money = 10000;
        yearID = 0;
        goodYears = 0;badYears = 0;
        records = new ArrayList();
        id++;
    }

    public void year() {
        yearID++;
        if(!getBankrupt()){
            spend();
        }
        writeRecords();
    }

    public void spend() {
        ...
    }

    public void printRecords() {
        for(int i=0;i<records.size();i++){
            String[] tmp = (String[]) records.get(i);
            for(String a:tmp){
                System.out.print(a+" ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");


        }

    }

    public void writeRecords(){
        String[] toWrite = new String[2];
        toWrite[0] = String.valueOf(yearID);
        toWrite[1] = String.valueOf(money);
        records.add(toWrite);
    }

    public void writeRecords(String toWrite){
        String temp = "\n"+yearID+"   "+toWrite;
        records.add(temp);
    }

    public boolean getBankrupt(){
        boolean result = (money < 0) ? true : false;
        return result;
    }


}
```

What I am trying to access it from:

```
public class grapher extends JFrame {
    ArrayList records = s.getRecords();

    public grapher(){
        super("ServiceProvider");
        final XYDataset dataset = getCompanyData();
    }



    private XYDataset getCompanyData(){
        XYSeries series;
        for(int i=0;i<s.getRecords().length;i++){ //S cannot be resolved, it's instantiated in the main class.

        }
    }

}
```

The main class:

```
public class start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceProvider s = new ServiceProvider();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            s.year();
        }
        s.printRecords();

    }

}
```

P.S. Don't tell me what a mess Records are. I know.

Comment: How much, if any, of all that code is relevant to the problem? Please edit and delete all code not *directly* related to the question. Even better, provide example code like `ClassA`, `ClassB` etc - see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the instance of `ServiceProvider` as an argument to the `grapher` constructor and then it can pass it as an argument to `getCompanyData()`.

Since the instance is created outside of the `grapher` class, there is no way for `grapher` to have the instance of `ServiceProvider` to work with unless you hand that instance to `grapher`.

BTW, make sure that whatever you do with that `ArrayList` in `grapher` that you don't change it.  If you do, you'll be changing it in the `ServiceProvider` (since it's all just references to the same underlying `ArrayList`).  That's probably not what you want to do.  If you do need to change it, make a copy and work with the copy.

Comment: Sorry. I tend to be long-winded.

Answer (score 0):

Your grapher class should be as follows

```
public class grapher extends JFrame {

    public grapher(ServiceProvider s){
        super("ServiceProvider");
        final XYDataset dataset = getCompanyData(s);
    }


    private XYDataset getCompanyData(ServiceProvider s){
        XYSeries series;
        for(int i=0;i<s.getRecords().length;i++){ 
                  // Do Process of business logic.   
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Your grapher class is trying to use a variable from the start class(you are making calls to variable s which exists in the start class), without having a reference to the variable. In order for grapher to access that instance, you'll have to pass it in to the grapher class as a paramater in the constructor:

```
public grapher(ServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
     records = serviceProvider.getRecords();
}
```

In the getCompanyData method, use your class variable records instead of s.